# How to pass self as Delegate

Tags: java, delegates

I'm creating a new object 'baby' from within class 'mother' which implements an interface containing one method 'feed' (the names are just for illustration).

How can I pass a pointer to the 'mother' class through the constructor of the 'baby' class? 
I want the baby class to be able to call the 'feed' method at any time throughout its lifetime.

What I had tried so far always produced compiler errors.

**Constructor of baby class**

```
public Baby(String name, Mother mother) {
    this.mother=mother;
    this.name=name;
}
```

**Code used to create the baby object** (inside Mother class)

```
Baby baby = new Baby("Brian",this);
```

Comment: Your code should work.  What error do you get?

Comment: It will fail in static context however.

Comment: Please post some code that actually doesn't work, will be much easier to help you with the different things that may be going wrong :)

Comment: I'm trying to create the baby object from inside a static main method in the Mother class. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I'm trying to create the baby object from inside a static main method in the Mother class.*

You can't pass `this` inside `static` context, e.g. as a `static` field, in a `static {}` initializer or in a `static method()` method. The static context applies to the class itself, not to a particular instance.

Do the job in the constructor or non-static field/method of `Mother` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In your main method of mother class, instantiate a Mother class and then pass it to Baby.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ....
  Mother mother = new Mother();
  Baby baby = new Baby("Brian", mother);
  ....
}
```